# How to configure which file extensions are served statically by Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, hippocms

In an existing java web app hosted on a Tomcat 6 server, I noticed that all URLs finishing with some specific extensions like `.png` or `.gif` are served statically whereas if I replace the extension by something more exotic like `.eot` then it gets handled by a servlet.

Where is this list of file extensions configured? I checked in `web.xml` and `server.xml` but did not find any mention to `png` or `gif`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in fact my problem was specific to Hippo CMS / Bloomreach Experience configuration (which is used in my project). It required to add an `.eot` to the list of `hst:suffixexclusions` property under `/hst:hst/hst:hosts` node, as described in [HippoCMS - Request Handling - Mount Matching](https://web.archive.org/web/20141204104430/http://www.onehippo.org:80/library/concepts/request-handling/mount-matching.html).

You can also instead add exlusion rules into `site/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/hst-config.properties` file:

```
filter.prefix.exclusions = /ping/, /fonts/
filter.suffix.exclusions = .eot, .woff, .woff2
```

This will solve the issue that Tomcat is returning HTTP 404 error code on most of font files.

Answer (score 4):

All files are served statically as long as no servlet(-mapping) is defined. The mime extensions are predefined in Tomcats default web.xml in folder /conf:

```
<!-- ===================== Default MIME Type Mappings =================== -->
<!-- When serving static resources, Tomcat will automatically generate    -->
<!-- a "Content-Type" header based on the resource's filename extension,  -->
<!-- based on these mappings.  Additional mappings can be added here (to  -->
<!-- apply to all web applications), or in your own application's web.xml -->
<!-- deployment descriptor.                                               -->

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>123</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
...
```

Comment: There is already a mime-mapping for the `eot` extension: `<mime-mapping><extension>eot</extension><mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type></mime-mapping>`. Why isn't it served like any other static resource then?

Comment: How is it served? I guess you mean not like a download but opening in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Stefoan sollution which is the optimal one `Tomcat AS` defines the `DefaultServlet` mapped to `default` as name and serves all the static resources (jpg,html,css,gif...) upon it. [Here you can find it's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/default-servlet.html).

So you can merely add a servlet mapping pointing to it to serve some custom file extension as a static resource:

```
<servlet-mapping>   
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.eot</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```